# Вызов из замыкания JS

Tags: javascript

Почему не выводится Alert? Понимаю, что замыкание, но почему не понятно. Как его вывести? Спасибо!

```
    var x = 10;
    function foo() {
        var y = 20;
        function bar() {
            var z = 15;
            var с = x + y + z;
            alert(c);
            return c;
        }
        return bar;
    }
    foo();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`foo()` возвращает функцию `bar`, `foo()()` - вызывает функцию `bar`:

```js
var x = 10;
function foo() {
  var y = 20;
  function bar() {
    var z = 15;
    var с = x + y + z; // в этой строчке использовано "с" из кириллицы
    console.log(c);    // в этой строчке использовано латинское "c"
    var c = x + y + z; // в этой строчке использовано латинское "c"
    console.log(c);    // в этой строчке использовано латинское "c"
    return c;          // в этой строчке использовано латинское "c"
  }
  return bar;
}
foo()();
```

Не называйте переменные буквами, которые выглядят одинаково в латинском и русском шрифтах.

Comment: Я поняла! Спасибо!))

Comment: А почему, если заменить foo()() на  var foo2 = foo() и потом вызвать foo2(), то тоже работает?

Comment: @Marina хм, потому что это правильно :). Переменная `foo2` указывает на функцию `bar`, которую вернул вызов `foo()`.

Comment: А каким образом присвоение функции другой переменной открывает доступ к вложенной функции bar?

Comment: @Marina тем образом, что функция `foo` возвращает функцию `bar`. Но я, видимо, плохо это объясняю.